# UINavigationbar loses set image on rotation

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, rotation, navigationbar

I have an app which starts with a root `UINavigationController`. This controller then pushes and pops various other `UIViewControllers` - that all works fine.

My app has a custom graphic for the `navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundImage`. There is one image for the iPhone platform. There are two images for the iPad platform - one for portrait, one for landscape. The iPad is the platform of issue as it rotates, the iPhone platform is portrait only.

I had already written code in `-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` to detect the rotation, and set the `navigationBar.backgroundImage` to the correct orientation graphic, if the platform is iPad.

In the iPad 5.0 simulator - it works fine; rotating the iPad on screen results in the correct navigationBar graphic regardless of orientation.

**On the device - it doesn't work** - The graphic appears correctly on iPad device launch in portrait. When I rotate to landscape, the navigationBar changes to a standard grey one. When I rotate back the grey 'sticks'.

I have tried calling `setNeedsDisplay` - no change.

I have tried setting `navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor]` - no change.

I have checked the filenames of the graphics in the code are identical to the actual filenames - they are.

Code for rotation:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    return YES; }
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
```

}

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        UIImage *titleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"StandardHeaderIpadLandscape"];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:titleImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StandardBackgroundiPadLandscape.png"]];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setNeedsDisplay];
    } else {
        UIImage *titleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"StandardHeaderIpadPortrait"];
         self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:titleImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StandardBackgroundiPad.png"]];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Show us the rotation methods. Check whether `navigationBar` is nil first. After that, we can discuss other potential issues involved.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the code above. I checked for existence with NSLog and it does exist.

Comment: What happens if you launch the app in landscape?  Does the image then show in that case?

Comment: Launching in landscape mode results in a grey bar as well. Launching in the iPad simulator in landscape works. There has to be something fundamentally different on the device, compared to the simulator - but I can't find anything in he docs (except that filenames have to be exact).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether `titleImage` is nil. I have a feeling that your image paths are not correct, or those images are not correctly copied to iPad.

Comment: Hi, you are spot on - checking for titleImage == nil; does trip my NSLog. Now I just have to work out why on earth it is nil. In fact, the portrait image reports as nil as well, on rotation. I didn't check for that - it seemed too obvious. Hubris!

Comment: Resolved - renamed both files to lowercase. Works. That's two hours of my life i'll never get back. Many thanks an0.